# Selecting a form from a dropdown form menu jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to make a school management system. So I am trying to choose class from menu after then the selected class student id will be displayed with a marks input field.

dropdown menu

```
Class 6,
Class 7,
Class 8
```

Inputs

```
form id=6
student id:1
input type="marks"

student id:2
input type="marks"
```

similarly

```
form id=7
student id:1
input type="marks"

student id:2
input type="marks"
```

When I will choose class 6 then form id=6 will be display.
Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CGqrH/)

Example HTML:

```
<select id="class_num">
    <option val=""></option>
    <option val="6">6</option>
    <option val="7">7</option>
    <option val="8">8</option>
</select>
<form id="6">
    <input type="text" value="class 6"/>
</form>
<form id="7">
    <input type="text" value="class 7"/>
</form>

<form id="8">
    <input type="text" value="class 8"/>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$("form").hide();
$("#class_num").change(function(){
     $("#"+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

Comment: I need to hide others form, only display my selected form.
How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Consider your Dropdown menu id was "ClassName"

    ** Jquery ** 

    $(function(){
    $('form').hide(); // hide all form
    $('#ClassName').change(function(){
    $('form').hide();
    $('form[id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
    });
    });
```

Comment: @ P.Sethuraman,   I need to hide others form, only display my selected form.
How is it possible ?

Comment: @ P.Sethuraman,   That is now worked perfectly, I change the code as

        $(function(){
        $('form').hide(); // hide all form
        $('#class_num').change(function(){
        $('form[id="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
        $('form[id!="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();
          });
       });

It works fine. Thanks.